# Vim Terminal - Solarized Colorscheme [Gnome]

Tags: terminal, colorscheme, plugin-solarized

I've tried

```
syntax on
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
set t_Co=256
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

but it doesn't look like GVim, how can I achieve that?

Right now
[image: Right now]

Comment: Are you running vim in terminal or gui? You used both gvim and terminal tags!

Comment: @EnanAjmain I want to run it in terminal, how can you see that?

Comment: Did you configure your terminal emulator according to the Solarized installation instructions?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker that's the problem, I don't know what to do exactly.

Comment: Since you don't know how to configure solarized colorscheme properly, I'm guessing you don't need the added customizability of it. Then, take a look at [this](https://github.com/lifepillar/vim-solarized8). It's easy to set up with simple hacks :)

Answer (score 4):

According to the [readme](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized#important-note-for-terminal-users) of the vim sector of ethan's solarized colorscheme, you need to set the colorscheme of your terminal explicitly. You can take a look at [base 16](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-shell). Install it, and run `base16_solarized-dark`. Then vim will, hopefully, show the colors properly. And also put this in your vimrc:

```
set termguicolors
```

in place of

```
set t_Co=256
```

Comment: If you want to also have the terminal using solarized, it is probably better indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue couple of weeks ago.

If you look inside of `solarized.vim`, you will find a section **GUI & CSApprox hexadecimal palettes** (in my case line 235).

There are a bunch of ifs, the 2 first being `if (has("gui_running") && ...)`

In the terminal, it does not, so depending on if you are using 16 or 256 colors, you will be in the 3rd or 4th `elseif`.

-If you really want the blue of Solarized, you can set your gnome-terminal profile to use solarized colors and change in `solarized.vim` the line:

```
let s:base03 = "234"
```

into

```
let s:base03 = "NONE"
```

To use the terminal's default color (base03 is used for the background color).

Although I am not persuaded than modifying the theme like that is the best to do (I tried to set the variable at the end of my `.vimrc` but it did not work).

And as I don't want to use solarized in my terminal, just in Vim, I stayed with the grey and 256 colors of solarized by default.

Answer (score 0):

Most people barely know about gnome terminal color setting, they just use existing tool to do the job.

- Use
  [gnome-terminal-colors-solarized](https://github.com/Anthony25/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized) to setup your terminal.
- use [dircolors-solarized](https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized) to fix directory color.
- if your terminal looks solarized, put `colorscheme solarized` in your .vimrc . That's all i need to get solarized colorsheme for neovim.

Don't waste your time on vim setting before you setup your terminal.

Comment: That could be considered as a waste of time only for those who want the same theme on their terminal and Vim.

Comment: Is that an option? I barely know this kind of stuff,  some site told me my solarized is degraded if i don't change my terminal.

Comment: I don't use solarized at all on my terminal (when I type commands), but use solarized in Vim. The OP asked about solarized in Vim when using in a terminal on Gnome, not necessarily to also have solarized in the terminal (out of Vim).

Comment: Gnome terminal? undegraded solarized color in vim?